# SUBSTITUTE Function and renaming Opportunity records based on Account Name Change

Tags: apex, formula, process-builder

I have a naming convention setup for the "Name" field on Account and Opportunity records.   Example:  ABC Company - 2323293

Using Process Builder, if an Account Name changes, I want to update the related Opportunity records to use the just the new name portion of the account.  If "ABC Company" changes to "DEF Company" then the related Opportunity record should end up with "DEF Company - 2323293".  I want to change everything to left of the hyphen on all child opportunity records.

Here is what I have in my formula within process builder, but the formula/logic is wrong and gives me an error saying the formula express is invalid.

```
SUBSTITUTE( 
Name, 
LEFT([Account].Name, FIND("-", [Account].Name)-1), 
LEFT([Account.Name], FIND("-", [Account.Name])-1)
)
```

Comment: Process Builder is on account, so when updating opportunity you cannot reference the name of the opportunity in it.  You have to go via trigger.

Comment: or, the PB can invoke a Lightning Flow that can change the Opportunity names

Comment: I thought you could update related records via process builder?